# When to use 很 vs 非常？

Tags: usage, difference

What is the difference between using 很 and 非常？

For example:
猫和狗都非常可爱 and 猫和狗都很可爱。Is there any difference? Which one should I use with 漂亮？

Comment: what is the difference between 'very' and 'extremely'?

Comment: A [question related](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/13943/is-there-a-difference-between-%e9%9d%9e%e5%b8%b8-and-%e5%be%88) has already been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a). "非常" usually is stronger.

猫和狗都非常可爱 (VERY VERY cute, VERY VERY adorable)

猫和狗都很可爱 (VERY cute, VERY adorable.)

E.g. bmw和benz都是好車，ferrari和lamborghini則是非常好的車。

b). You COULD use 漂亮 for both sentences.

猫和狗都很漂亮

猫和狗都非常漂亮

c). You also can use 漂亮 and 可愛 in one sentence.

猫和狗都很漂亮、很可愛。

猫和狗都非常漂亮、非常可愛。

But sometimes you might not use 可爱 to replcace 漂亮, and vice versa.

E.g

你的貓毛色很可愛(Your cat's fur color is so cute). It's understandable, but sounds a little odd. Use 漂亮 is better than 可愛。

Answer (score 0):

Usually in our oral speaking, they hae no difference.

HungYu said 非常 is stronger, but I have a little opinion. The way you speak the word also affect the expression.
For example, you can length the syllable to express your feeling.

1. 猫和狗都feiiiiiiiiiii chang可爱.
2. 猫和狗都hennnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn可爱.

See, no difference.